# boto ec2 connect to region is not working in a EC2 instance in Amazon VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

```
ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(regionName)
```

gets hung in a instance in VPC. 
boto ec2 connect to region is not working in a EC2 instance in Amazon VPC but the same thing works outside Amazon VPC.

What are the things I need to check ?

Thank you

Comment: It's good that you accepted an answer, but you should also leave a response so that the next person who comes along via a Google knows how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VPC adds egress rules to Security Groups. It also adds a new feature called Network ACLs that adds stateless ingress and egress rules. Check both your Network ACLs and Security Groups to make sure that you aren't blocking anything with egress rules.